# Read all Android contacts in Mono for Android

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

How do I read all contact on Android phone using C# on Mono for Android? I have seen a lot of Java examples.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple example up [here](https://github.com/gshackles/Sample-Projects/blob/master/MonoDroid/MonoDroidSamples/MonoDroidSamples/DemoActivities/Contacts/ContactsActivity.cs) that lists out all the contacts from the device into a list using the built-in content provider.

The real meat of the sample is this:

```
_list = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.contact_list);

var contacts = ManagedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri, null, null, null, null);

_list.Adapter = 
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, 
        Resource.Layout.contacts_item, 
        contacts, 
        new string[] { ContactsContract.ContactsColumnsConsts.DisplayName }, 
        new int[] { Resource.Id.contact_name });
```

The ManagedQuery method queries the provided content provider (contacts, in this case) and returns a cursor with the results. The other arguments to the method can be used to specify selection criteria. Here, supplying null for everything returns all the contacts.

Xamarin also has a their [Xamarin.Mobile API](http://blog.xamarin.com/2011/12/08/cross-platform-contacts-api/) which is currently in preview, and provides some nicer methods for accessing contact data (and some other things).

Comment: Sorry guys I am still new at this Android Dev. Thanks for the code Greg but I am still having a slight problem with 
        Resource.Layout.contacts_item
It breaks because contacts_item cannot be found in the Resources file and I see that resources is a generated file. How do I resolve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Right, the snippet there depends on other parts of the application (which are also included in that link). For example, the resource files are located here: https://github.com/gshackles/Sample-Projects/tree/master/MonoDroid/MonoDroidSamples/MonoDroidSamples/Resources/layout